# purpose of eval in this case

Tags: php, javascript, eval

I am studying a custom framework. I found a code like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?php
    echo "ABC.Variables.Objects = eval('(" . $Objects . ")');";
?>
</script>
```

and in see source i saw code like

```
ABC.Variables.Objects = eval('({"success":true,"results":11})');
```

what was the main purpose of using EVAL in this case? Is is working on client side of server side?

Comment: if eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question

Comment: There *is* no purpose for using `eval` in this case.  PHP code sloppily ported from Javascript that was using AJAX, maybe?  But even then `eval` would not be the way to go.  In general, `eval` should be avoided, as it is dangerous from both a stability and security standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

`eval` here is use to turn the json format string to a javascript object. The right way to do this is to use `JSON.parse(str)` or some json parse functions for old browsers.

**But you don't need to use `eval` in such case, even `JSON.parse()` is not necessary.**

You just need to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // of course $Objects needs to be a valid json string, eg the result of json_encode 
  ABC.Variables.Objects = <?php echo $Objects ?>;
</script>
```

And in the source you should see:

```
ABC.Variables.Objects =　{"success":true,"results":11};
```

No eval is needed.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha So what it is supposed to be? My point is `eval` is not necessary, you even don't need `JSON.parse` in such case.

Comment: @xdazz - Suppose i want to convert it into a javascript object then a string, then can i use it JSON.parse ????

Comment: @hacker no, you do not need, just echo it directly.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP has output JavaScript code to be executed by the client browser.  In the JavaScript (*not the PHP*), `eval()`  is called to parse a JSON string  which was originally stored in a PHP variable `$Objects` into a JavaScript object.

Rather than `eval()`, it really ought to be calling `JSON.parse()`.

Would have been better:

```
echo "ABC.Variables.Objects = JSON.parse('" . $Objects . "');";
```

Comment: If `$Objects` is already an json format string, there is no need to use `JSON.parse()`. If you could use `var a = {"a":1};` why you need to do `var a = JSON.parse('{"a":1}');`

Answer (score 0):

Here, the eval function converts a json string into json object.